# Web Publish to Package Hangs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.NET MVC website project that is a few years old.  When it's time to deploy an update to QA or Production, I use Web Publish to create a ZIP file and related .cmd file.

It worked fine this morning.  Then I updated the project from source control.  Now, when I right-click the project and select `Publish...`, Visual Studio 2013 hangs.  After some initial research, I have tried the following:

- Run as Administrator
- Disable Anti-Virus (temporarily)
- Clean the solution
- Delete the .suo and .csproj files
- Rebooted
- Gave it 20 minutes to see if it unhangs

I also deleted the /Properties/PublishProfiles folder with the existing .pubxml files.  When I do that, the publishing wizard opens and allows me to name a custom profile, at which point it, along with Visual Studio, hangs.  No .pubxml file is written in this case.

While Visual Studio is hanging, it is not consuming any significant CPU.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, another developer inadvertently checked in a change to web.config, providing an incorrect connection string for the application's database.  The web application startup code accesses the database to pre-cache some information.  I'm unsure why there is no connection timeout, but that is not relevant to answering this question.

The Web Publish wizard must be causing the web application to run.  Since that startup code was essentially hanging, so did the Web Publish wizard.